# VLC Python Bindings -- Error 193

Tags: python, vlc

Have downloaded VLC.py, and placed it in my VLC install directory, where libvlc.dll is also present

On typing `import vlc`

I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.py", line 88,
>   in 
>       dll = ctypes.CDLL('libvlc.dll')   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes__init__.py",
>   line 353, in **init**
>       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is
>   not a valid Win32 application

Any ideas why?

If needed, my config is:
Win7 pro 64 bit
4GB RAM

Comment: Is that a 64-bit build of python?

Comment: I'm going to guess that the problem is trying to load a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit process. You may be able to fix it by using a 32-bit Python build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer, since it fixed the problem:

> I'm going to guess that the problem is trying to load a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit process. You may be able to fix it by using a 32-bit Python build.