# libsvm in Python : getting error

Tags: python-2.7, svm, libsvm

I am new to Python. I wanted to use svm for my project. I was using libsvm 3.12 but when i do ..

```
from svm import *
```

then i get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Python27/main.py", line 31, in 
    from svm import *
  File "C:/Python27\svm.py", line 12, in 
    libsvm = CDLL(find_library('libsvm'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What should I do?

The `libsvm` `README` file suggested that I copy `libsvm.dll` into the `system32` folder, which I did .. but still I am getting the error. I am using 64 bit Python. Maybe that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same issue.

As Velociraptors posted in [VLC Python Bindings -- Error 193](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007455/vlc-python-bindings-error-193):

> I'm going to guess that the problem is trying to load a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit process. You may be able to fix it by using a 32-bit Python build.

We solved the issue by downloading libSVM for python from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libsvm